# Can I wire a secondary 240V breaker box for lab equipment from Europe?

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, 240v

I have a dental lab in Europe and might want to move it to the USA. Some of the equipment rates as high as 4kW, and the the total maximum draw is 15kW for the whole lab. Can I wire a secondary breaker box in a building in the United States that is all 240V?

Comment: Depending on the type of power service delivered to the building, you may not have 240v available to you. If the service is bi-phase, then 240v is possible. If the service is 3-phase, then you will get 208v.

Comment: @nvarras7 How did this work out? Did you relocate?

Answer (score 7):

Yes. The bigger problem is going to be if any of the equipment requires 50 Hz or is not approved here (e.g., Commercial U.L. or whatever code and insurance requires for a dental lab).

Comment: Thank you for the response, none of the equipment says 50 or 60 Hz, that mean it's ok?  all the equipment comes in US 110v versions if that helps, but buying them all again is about $400k too prohibitive.

Comment: You can't assume that it's OK. You may have to look more carefully for small print, look for specifications in the manuals, or even ask the manufacturers.

Comment: I'd assume that no explicit specification would mean 50 Hz on European equipment. It's worth finding the datasheet.

Comment: @nvarras7 The equipment should have a nameplate with information like manufacturer, voltage, current, possibly Volt-Amperes, etc. It would likely be near where the electrical cable (cord) connects to the equipment (or possibly just inside a panel where the power connects).

Comment: Ok thanx to all for the answers, most of the machines documents list 50-60Hz, only one has 50 Hz on the plate, so I think I'm good!  Now, can anyone lend a hand at moving time? Lol!